# In MySQL, how do I select * from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two separate tables on MySQL, and I want to make a query where I select * from both of them and I want to order them by id (or date). The problem is the id's will conflict, since there will be two articles with the same id (one from each table).

Is there a way where I can display all the articles of each table in one single query?

Edit:

They don't have the same number of columns. However, I will be choosing the same columns of each of them. So I'd be selecting "id, map, title, summary, image, date, publish" from both table1 and table2. (because both of the tables have those exact same columns).

Then I want to display on a single web page all the articles from both table1 and table2. In the exact same grid.

Is this even possible or do I need to merge both tables in MySQL?

Comment: Use aliases to uniquely identify in order clause. It's a bad habit using * in my opinion.

Comment: You can use alias for tables `select a.id a_id, b.id b_id from tbl1 a, tbl2 b where a.id = b.id order by a_id`

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two tables? Do you want to `JOIN` them? What **exactly** are you trying to do, be specific - as it stands it's a little hard to answer this question with anything other than "yes" (which isn't helpful I know ;) )

Comment: You can use *UNION* but if both *id*s are same which should appear first?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can select *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 tables have the same number of columns and the data types of the corresponding columns are the same, then you can use `UNION ALL:`

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
ORDER BY id
```

If you also want to distinguish the rows so you know from which table they originate, you can create a dummy 1st column for each of them like this:

```
SELECT '1' fromtable, * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' fromtable, * FROM table2
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: They don't have the same number of columns. However, I will be choosing the same columns of each of them. So I'd be selecting "id, map, title, summary, image, date, publish" from both table1 and table2. (because both of the tables have those exact same columns).

Is this even possible or do I need to merge both tables in MySQL?

Comment: If you select the same number of columns with the same data types then you can do it. The names will be selected from the 1st query.

Comment: So would it be something like this?

SELECT id, map, title, summary, image, date, publish FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, map, title, summary, image, date, publish FROM table2
ORDER BY id

Comment: YES THAT WORKED! Ty alot!